# Equivalent characterization for $O_{\pi}(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $\pi$ is a set of primes, define $O_{\pi}(G)$ to be the subgroup of $G$ generated by all the normal $\pi$-subgroups of $G$.
>
> Show that $O_{\pi}(G)$ is the intersection of all maximal $\pi$-subgroups of $G$.

Let $H$ to be the intersection of all maximal $\pi$-subgroups of $G$.
Let $\sigma\in Aut(G)$.
Then $\sigma$ permutes the maximal $\pi$-subgroups.
Hence $\sigma(H)= H$ and $H$ char $G$.
This means that $H\lhd G$ and by definition $H\leq O_{\pi}(G)$.

Now I need to show $O_{\pi}(G)\le H$.
I guess the idea will be show that every normal $\pi$-subgroup is contained in every maximal $\pi$-subgroup but I can't see why it is true.

Comment: Is $G$ assumed to be finite ? If yes, do you know the Sylow theorems ?

Comment: @Max This question appears under the section about Hall's Theorem so I think that $G$ is assumed to be finite. And yes I know about Sylow theorems but it can only be applied when $\pi=\{p\}$.

Comment: In that case (I thought $\pi$ was a prime number) you should add what $\pi$ is and what a $\pi$-subgroup is. And I'm not sure because I haven't seen the definitions but I'm confident one will still be able to apply Sylow's theorems, although not directly

Comment: Hint: If $K$ is maximal $\pi$-subgroup, what is the order of the subgroup $KO_{\pi}(G)$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician By product formula, $$|KO_{\pi}|=|K||O_{\pi}|/|K\cap O_{\pi}|$$

Comment: And isn't this a $\pi$-number? and isn't $K$ maximal? and so ....

Comment: @ancientmathematician I can get your idea but how to make sure that $|O_{\pi}|/|K\cap O_{\pi}|$ is a $\pi$-number too?

Comment: Well by Lagrange it suffices to prove $O_{\pi}$ is a $\pi$-group. As it is generated by normal $\pi$-subgroups the product formula will give us what we need. (In fact $O_{\pi}$ is the maximal normal $\pi$-subgroup.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anything wrong within your proof that $H$ is a characteristic subgroup and therefore a normal subgroup. And, $H$ is also a $\pi$-subgroup because every element in $H_i$ has order a $\pi$-number, so does every element in $H$. So why don't they define $O_{\pi}(G)$ as the maximal normal $\pi$-subgroup?

For your part, I want to prove by saying that every normal $\pi$-subgroup $N$ is a subgroup of every maximal $\pi$-subgroup $H_i$, because otherwise (at least in finite case), $NH_i$ is a larger $\pi$-subgroup (this is because $|NH_i|=\frac{|N||H_i|}{|N \cap H_i|}$ is a $\pi$-number, as Cauchy's theorem tells us that $|N|,|H_i|$ are $\pi$-numbers). So every generator of the group is a subgroup of the intersection. So the group $O_{\pi}(G)$ generated by them is also a subgroup of the intersection.

Not sure whether I am correct. Hope anyone can share their thoughts.